# How Do I Capture when the Cluster Rendering is Completed

Tags: clustering, arcgis-silverlight-api, rendering

I have a graphics layer that draws clusters using the sample custom cluster from ESRI.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#CustomClusterer

We have a Busy Indicator that we pop up during long calculations to let the user know that something is happening.  I would like to pop up this indicator during the clustering, and have it go away once the clusters have done drawing on the screen.  I can turn it on, but I am not able to capture a "done rendering" event to turn off the indicator.  I've tried capturing the  LayoutUpdated event on the Map, but it gets sent several times and am not able to determine which one is the graphics layers saying its done rendering.  I found the  OnClusteringCompleted event of the GraphicsClusterer and tried to override it by adding it to the custom clusterer but the code never gets there.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want?